# DataRow[] Aggregate Functions C#

Tags: c#, aggregate

I have an array of DataRow objects in my C# project which I would like to Sum various fields from.

Instead of running through each row and totalling my own sums I noticed the DataRow[].Sum<> function but I am struggling to find any resources on the net on how to use it.

Any pointers in the right direction would be very helpful

:) Removed code example as it was wrong! All now works fine - the link helped cheers Marc.

Comment: Can you please share how you initialized the rows object, used in Marc Gravell's snippet?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

That is the LINQ `Sum`; and can be used:

```
var sum = rows.Sum(row => row.Field<int>("SomeColumn")); // use correct data type
```

(you can also pass in the column index or the `DataColumn` in place of the string)

for untyped datarows, or:

```
var sum = rows.Sum(row => row.SomeColumn);
```

for typed datarows.

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.sum.aspx) has full documentation on this; for example, [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb535184.aspx) is the overload I am using in the examples above.

Comment: Sorry I'm probably being really dumb here but haven't used LINQ  before :) How do you get a reference to the row if I'm not iterating through the array?

Comment: The `Sum` method does the iteration. The " row => row.SomeColumn " (etc) could be interpreted as "given a row, do this", and is a delegate that is evaluated for each row. So in this case, it says "for each row, evaluate row.SomeColumn, summing them".

Comment: (so each time the "row => row.SomeColumn" operates, `row` is a different `DataRow`, if you see what I mean)

Comment: Add a link to some LINQ to Object documentation :)

Comment: @Marc Gravell: I have a very similar requirement as the OP. Can you please show how you initalized the variable "rows" in your example? All I have is mydataset.Tables[0].Rows collection. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This is my way to use sum number fields in DataRow of Datatable.

I share for whom concern.

```
DataTable retrieveData = GetData();
decimal value = 0;
var total = retrieveData.Rows[i].ItemArray.Sum(row => 
    decimal.TryParse(row.ToString(), out value) ? decimal.Parse(row.ToString()) : 0);
```