# DataRow[] Aggregate Functions C# - Appendix

Tags: c#, linq, ienumerable, datarow

My question arised out of the accept answer here:

[DataRow[] Aggregate Functions C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1617518/datarow-aggregate-functions-c)

In that answer, how is the "rows" object intialized?

EDIT: 
In my case, I have mydataset.Tables[0].Rows collection, from which I need to SUM a particular column.

Comment: Your starting point is a Linq problem, but your later edit makes me wonder if `DataTable.Compute` wouldn't be just what you need.

Comment: This might just work. I will try and post an update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably from a LINQ query like:

```
List<DataRow> rows = (from row in mydataset.Tables[0].AsEnumerable()
                      select row).ToList();
```

Comment: I tried, and got `Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Data.EnumerableRowCollection<System.Data.DataRow>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<System.Data.DataRow>'`

Answer (score 2):

Well you can create your own list of `DataRow`

```
List<DataRow> listOfRows = new List<DataRow>();
```

Or you can get collection of them from GridView.

```
var rows = gridView.Tables[0].Rows; //will return a collection of DataRows from your Gridview
```

Or from DataSet

```
var rows = dataSet.Tables[0].Rows;
```

Comment: When I try to do it like this

`List<DataRow> rows = myDataSet.Tables[0].Rows;`

I get this:

Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Data.DataRowCollection' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<System.Data.DataRow>'

Comment: Correct as you would be returning a collection of DataRows which is different to List<DataRow>. Try this. var rows = myDataSet.Tables[0].Rows;

Comment: @Jethro The Sum method doesn't exist for a DataRowCollection so that's not really helpful

Comment: @Brian Gordon, are you looking for the Sum Function? You will need to have using System.Linq; And reseach Linq to DataSets, I know you can use it, I just havn't with dataSets though.

Comment: @Jethro FMFF said he wants to use Sum, and that's how the `rows` variable was being used in the answer he linked to

Comment: @Brian Gordon, sorry didn't see his update. His first question was only how was it Initialized.